# How to load entity by UUID from url argument?

Tags: entities, 8, routes

Usually routes have `{entity_type}` in their routes's path and Drupal loads the entity by its ID.

I need to load entities by their UUID, so the path would look like /node/0ff3b31b-5abb-4377-bb00-af71882e38a4.

Is it possible to have a route that allows to load entities by their UUID? Do I need to create a `ParamConverter` class for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need your own param converter for this, the default implementation can only load by UUID.

Loading by UUID is less performant as long as the primary ID is still a serial ID, this means that it first needs to do an entity query to fetch the ID and then load that.

Comment: There's this issue on DO: [Make it possible to link to an entity by UUID](https://www.drupal.org/node/2353611).